# Folder Explorer

Tags: c#, jquery, .net, asp.net-mvc

I´m developing an intranet where I need to select a server side folder to store some data. It has to be on the server side, so I need a to create partial view where a user can navigate through server folder structure (commonly network mapper drive) and choose a folder.

I have this now:

```
List<string> dirs = new List<string>(Directory.EnumerateDirectories(dirPath));

List<string> files = new List<string>();
DirectoryInfo dirInfo = new DirectoryInfo(dirPath);
foreach (string fInfo in Directory
                         .EnumerateFiles(dirPath, "*.*", SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly)
                         .Where(s => s.EndsWith(".png")
                                || s.EndsWith(".PNG")
                                || s.EndsWith(".jpg")
                                || s.EndsWith(".JPG")
                         ).Select(Path.GetFileName))
{
    files.Add(fInfo);
}
```

But did someone know a jQuery library or something to make a user select a server side folder?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You can simplify this loop using the MimeMapping object

MimeMapping.GetMimeMapping("file.png"); // => "image/png"

So your loop can loop over and grab all the files that meet particular mime types (image/*, text/*, etc...)

Consider using a restful ajax approach to uploading data to the server

```
POST /client_data/image.png

binary image data
```

your server logic could then parse out the image and store it locally

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mimemapping.getmimemapping(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: that isn´t what I need. I need something to give users abillity to choose a serverside directory where some data will be stored. This folder will be outside of the web server. They need to navigate through server file system